# Pass data from ul/li Blade element to controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I'm trying to figure out how to pass data from a ul/li element to a controller in Blade.  I found an answer found here:

[how to pass data from blade file to Controller in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902269/how-to-pass-data-from-blade-file-to-controller-in-laravel)

In it they explain how to pass data:

```
$permission->collaborator_id = $request->input('cid');
```

However, this does not work in a ul / li drop down.  My code contains the following:

```
      <ul class="d-none po-list" id="size">
        @foreach ($productDetails as $productDetail)
        <li name="size" value="{{ $productDetail->ID }}"><span>{{ $productDetail->title }}</span></li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
```

From here I wish to pass the value of {{ $productDetail->ID }} into my controller.  I've tried these two approaches:

```
 <ul class="d-none po-list" id="size" name="size">
    @foreach ($productDetails as $productDetail)
    <li value="{{ $productDetail->ID }}"><span>{{ $productDetail->title }}</span></li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
```

and

```
 <ul class="d-none po-list" id="size">
    @foreach ($productDetails as $productDetail)
    <li name="size" value="{{ $productDetail->ID }}"><span>{{ $productDetail->title }}</span></li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
```

I then attempt to call it using this in my controller:

```
$productOrderDetails->size_id = $request->input('size');
```

I believe the problem is that I'm not passing an "input" but selected li: checking documentation I don't find anything for request -> selected or request -> li.

Comment: <li> is not an input element. This has nothing to do with Laravel. You need to Google HTML form elements and use on of those to send form data. Possibly, have a hidden input with the desired value

Comment: I specifically said the problem is I’m not passing an input but wanted to know how to do it with lli @Paras

Comment: you cannot pass li data in forms

Comment: Without a form element like input it is not possible

Comment: ok makes perfect sense.  Thank you! @Paras

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in your blade template you have to create input fields for your data. It can be hidden or non hidden in a form to and a button for submission . Through this form data you have to make a get or post request to the server according to your data . It is something like this

In Blade template

```
<form method="post" action="{{your request url}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"></div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="Name">Product Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="Price">Product Price:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"></div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4" style="margin-top:10px">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Now in your controller you can fetch it like this ( with validator function)

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
    ]);
   $product = new Product();
   $product->name = $request->get('name');
   $product->price = $request->get('price');
   $product->save();
   return redirect('products')->with('success','Employee has been added');
  }
```